# Symfony - How can I use the $event->getPasswordToken() to work?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I am trying to implement a password reset feature to an already made Symfony 3.4 application. I am at the point where I need to check the user token that was send by email and compare it to the one saved in the database. I can't seem to use the $event->getPasswordToken() in my code ...

> Controller "AppBundle\Controller\ResettingController::resetting()" requires that you provide a value for the "$event" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.

```
<?php 

namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormErrorIterator;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Form\ResettingType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ListenerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Twig\Environment;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenGenerator\TokenGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
use AppBundle\Services\Mailer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use CoopTilleuls\ForgotPasswordBundle\Event\ForgotPasswordEvent;
use CoopTilleuls\ForgotPasswordBundle\Entity\AbstractPasswordToken;
use AppBundle\Event;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

/**
 * @Route("/password-change")
 */
class ResettingController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/{token}", name="resetting")
     * @param ResettingController $event
     */
    public function resetting(ForgotPasswordEvent $event, User $user, $token, Request $request)
    {

        die($token." -> ".$event->getPasswordToken());

        if ($user->getToken() === null || $token !== $user->getToken())
        {
            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('error', "Lien d'accès invalide");
            return $this->redirectToRoute('security_login');
        }

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                                            ->add('_password1', PasswordType::class, array("label"=>"Entrez un nouveau mot de passe:"))
                                            ->add('_password2', PasswordType::class, array("label"=>"Retapez ce même mot de passe:"))
                                            ->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $encoder = $this->get('security.password_encoder');
            $password = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
            $user->setPassword($password);
            // réinitialisation du token à null pour qu'il ne soit plus réutilisable
            $user->setPasswordToken(null);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', "Votre mot de passe a été modifié.");
            return $this->redirectToRoute('security_login');
        } 

        return $this->render('Security/change-password.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'title' => "Changement de mot de passe",
            'error' => $form->getErrors()
        ]);

    }
}
```

(I am sorry about all the use in the header ... I made a lot os testing to get the code to work and not sure which one needs to remain lol Gona look at that later on)

The die returns the token in the URL but is blank on the token from the database and returns that error. I am trying to get the $event working in order to use the `getPasswordToken()` function.

That fonction is currently used with sucess in the following controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Event;
use CoopTilleuls\ForgotPasswordBundle\Event\ForgotPasswordEvent;

class ForgotPasswordEventListener
{

    private $templating;
    private $mailer;
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $templating, \Swift_Mailer $mailer, \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $manager)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->manager=$manager;
    }

    /**
     * @param ForgotPasswordEvent $event
     */
    public function onCreateToken(ForgotPasswordEvent $event)
    {
        $passwordToken = $event->getPasswordToken();
        $user = $passwordToken->getUser();

        $swiftMessage = new \Swift_Message(
            'Reset of your password',
            $this->templating->render(
             'Security/forgot-password.html.twig',
                [
                    'reset_password_url' => sprintf('http://www.quebecenreseau.servlinks.com/intranet/password-change/%s/%s', $user->getId(), $passwordToken->getToken()),
                ]
            )
        );

        $swiftMessage->setFrom('patrick.simard@servlinks.com');
        $swiftMessage->setTo($user->getEmail());
        $swiftMessage->setContentType('text/html');
        if (0 === $this->mailer->send($swiftMessage)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Unable to send email');
        }
    }

/*
        public function onUpdatePassword(ForgotPasswordEvent $event)
        {
            $passwordToken = $event->getPasswordToken();
            $user = $passwordToken->getUser();
            $user->setPlainPassword($event->getPassword());
            $this->manager->persist($user);
        }
*/

}
```

This is my service file:

```
# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

parameters:
#    parameter_name: value

services:
    app.security.login_form_authenticator:
        class: AppBundle\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
        autowire: true

    app.doctrine.hash_password_listener:
        class: AppBundle\Doctrine\HashPasswordListener
        autowire: true
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber }

    app.locale_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
        arguments: ['%kernel.default_locale%','@security.authorization_checker']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }

    app.login_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
        arguments: ['@session']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onInteractiveLogin }

    app.mailer:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Mailer
        arguments: ['@mailer','@templating']

    app.utility:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Utility
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']

    app.filemanager:
        class: AppBundle\Service\FileManager

    app.twig_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        arguments: ['@translator.default','@request_stack']
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }       
    app.sae:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Entity\Sae
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']

    app.document:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Entity\Document
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']

    app.professional:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Entity\Professional
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']

    app.article:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Entity\Article
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']

    app.course:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Entity\Course
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']

    app.useraddon:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Entity\UserAddon
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']

    app.jwt_token_authenticator:
        class: AppBundle\Security\JwtAuthenticator
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder']

    app.listener.forgot_password:
        class: AppBundle\Event\ForgotPasswordEventListener      
        arguments:
            - "@twig"
            - "@mailer"
            - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.create_token, method: onCreateToken}
            - { name: templating.helper, alias: templating, event: coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.create_token, method: onCreateToken}
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.update_password, method: onUpdatePassword }

    app.ResettingController:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\ResettingController
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: app.ResettingController }


    kernel.event_listener.json_request_transformer:
        class: Qandidate\Common\Symfony\HttpKernel\EventListener\JsonRequestTransformerListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 100 }
```

The token is saved inside a seperate table like this:
[image]

I need to compare the save token with the one in the URL and then delete the token from the database after the user submits the new password.

So fare all my attempts to use the function from the other controller has failed.

Answer (score 0):

PasswordToken have to be an attributes of entity user. So you can check it at anytime